# How to sum a gift amount with out duplicate gifts

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have a table like this--

```
GiftImpID  GiftAmt   Category
12345       12.00    Donation
12345       12.00    Donation
56789       10.00    Donation
56789       10.00    Donation
7890         5.00    Sale
```

So I need the DISTINCT(GiftImpID) and the GiftAmt added for each Category.

I need to get

```
GiftAmt   Category
22.00     Donation
5.00      Sale
```

I have tried

```
Select SUM(Giftamt), Category From #MDevReport 
Where GiftImpID
IN(Select DISTINCT(giftImpID) FROM #MDevReport) 
GROUP BY Category
```

But I'm still getting duplicates added in the sum...

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery :

```
select sum(GiftAmt), Category 
from (select distinct GiftImpID, GiftAmt, Category 
      from #MDevReport 
     ) t
group by Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select category, sum(GiftAmt)
from (select Category, GiftImpID, avg(GiftAmt) as GiftAmt
      from #MDevReport 
      group by Category, GiftImpID
     ) dr
group by category;
```

Then, fix your data model.  Obviously repeating the values in each row is not appropriate.

Comment: @AccessProgrammer . . . It is a table alias.